# Useful keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

## Useful keyboard shortcuts for programmers:

<kbd>Home</kbd> - Go to the beginning of the linen ||
<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> - **For Mac**

<kbd>End</kbd> - Go to the end of the line ||
<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> - **For Mac**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> - Select the entire line from where the selector is ||
<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> - **For Mac**

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> - Move the entire line up or down

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> - Move move selector word by word

Hope to help the community to programm faster

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.